# How do I disable login for softdeleted users?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

I have a softdeleted users, but currently the system still allow these softdeleted users to login. I've tried putting condition to my login function but still not working.

*p/s: i'm new to react-spring*

this is my login function:

```
if (this.checkBtn.context._errors.length === 0 ) {
      AuthService.login(this.state.username, this.state.password).then(
        () => {
          if (this.state.softDelete === 1){
          if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).roles[0]==="ADMIN"){
            
            this.props.history.push("/admin");
          }
          else{this.props.history.push("/profile");}
          window.location.reload();
        }},
        error => {
          const resMessage =
            (error.response &&
              error.response.data &&
              error.response.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString();

          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            message: resMessage
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
    }
```

Comment: Is ```this.state.softDelete === 1``` means that the user is soft deleted ???

Comment: When is the softdelete state variable set? isnt it be returned in the login api call?

Comment: @Umeshwaran 1 is if the user is active, 0 is if the user is soft deleted. it should be: if user active, able to login. if user has been soft deleted, user is unauthorized to login.

Comment: @G_S i have an employee (user) table consists of their information including soft delete variable. when the admin creates new user, the state should be 0 (means active). when the admin soft deletes a user, the state will become 1 (means unactive)

Comment: Try logging the value of ```this.state.softDelete``` before ```if(this.state.softDelete===1)```.Do console log and check the value